Angular 16 Migration : Compilation issues Not importing modules of bootstrap or any 3rd party libs used
I am upgrading my application from Angular 14 to 16. I am facing lot of compilation issues. All are related to bootstrap and FormModule issues(I imported latest and compatible  versions).Error: ./sample.component.html:1:7 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. 1 <form [formGroup]="formGroup" autocomplete="off">
This issue is resolved after I import ReactiveFormsModule in component. example something like,
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';      
@Component({
      selector: 'app-sample',
      standalone: true,  
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./job-costing-departments.component.scss']
    })

My Question is I have already imported  ReactiveFormsModule in my core.module. like below,
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        
      ],
      exports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule
      ]
    })
    export class CoreModule { }

I am importing this core.module in my implementaion.module like below (sample components placed here),
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    ImplementationRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SampleComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SampleComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ImplementationService
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

})
export class ImplementationModule { }

Why its throwing errors If I already imported module in core module ? same issues with NgbDatePicker and etc. this is working fine in Angular 15 but not after upgraded to Angular 16. I don't want to fix like importing again modules in component (as its showing 1000 errors in different components). Please advice if I am doing wrong.
Thank you!

I have upgraded my 3rd Party libraries and imported required 3rd party modules into component. as Angular 16 I see standalone introduced. I imported my required modules in components itself like imports : [module1, module2, etc..]. I fixed all issues related fixed like this.

Please elaborate for future people that may have this issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Sure I updated it.
